# Reading SMS messages from Inbox

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read the SMS messages from the user's inbox, but I only get the Number, as `cur.getString()` allways returns NULL to me, After an Index of 2...

Here is my code :

```
        TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

      Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
      Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
      String sms = "";
      while (cur.moveToNext()) 
      {
          sms += "From :" + cur.getString(2) + " : " + cur.getString(11)+"\n";
          Log.i("MyApp", "A " + cur.getString(2) + " " + cur.getString(3));
      }

      view.setText(sms);
```

I've checked, and `cur.getString(3)` and above, allways returns null to me...

What is my error?

Thanks!

Edit :
thanks to simas, I've seen that the `body` field that contains the message data, is field number 12 in the Cursor (`cur)`, and not 11. so changing it from 11 to 12 fixed it. 
Thanks simas!

Comment: Add some logging to check nulls then post your logcat results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
cur.moveToFirst();
if (cur != null) {
    do {    
       sms += "From :" + cur.getString(2) + " : " + cur.getString(11)+"\n";
           Log.i("MyApp", "A " + cur.getString(2) + " " + cur.getString(3));        
    }while(cur.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: the line `Log.i("MyApp", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("person")));` crashes my application...

Comment: i think you should add cur.moveToFirst(); before while

Comment: not all phones store the SMS data with the same content provider
so try to see the results of this:
Log.i("COLUMNS", Arrays.toString(cur.getColumnNames()));

Comment: And Arrays.toString with getColumnNames returns some randon Hex - string such as `FDX515S` - Is that the adress of the string ?

Comment: as android developers site says: Returns a string array holding the names of all of the columns in the result set in the order in which they were listed in the result.
but it has to be like [id,body,...]
did you insert READ_SMS permission into your android manifest file?

Comment: Thank you! I've got a list of all the fiels, it was field number 12, not 11.